# Can I use a car battery to power my robot?

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, load

I'm building a machine which can fly a kite. It uses a camera to follow the kite in the air, and based on that it pulls the wires using an electro motor which hangs in the air under the kite.

So far I just have a test setup in my house, but I now want to take it outside. At some point I need to strap a battery to the electro motor in the air, but that means I need to buy a pretty large (and expensive) LiPO battery pack while I don't even know if my machine is going to work.

So for now I just want to have a power source at the ground and a wire that goes up to my kite to power the motor. So I thought of simply wiring it up to a car battery. Since the electro motor below the kite is 24V (8A) I need a converter to convert my car battery power from 12V to 24V (such as [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/WH-B1224-600-WEHO-12v-to-24v-25a-600w-DC-DC-converter/32725173832.html)).

The electro motor in the air will be turning right and left interchangably and it will run about half of the time.

My question is; can a regular car battery even handle that kind of load (if needed I can of course keep the car motor running)?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: It should handle that for a little while, engine running would be better. Bigger question is can your kite lift a cable capable of carrying 8A that distance without significant voltage drop along the cables. That also seems like an very large motor for what you are trying to do.

Comment: A 6S lipo is about the price of that converter, FYI -- if not cheaper.

Comment: Have the motor on the ground, and steering cables going up to the kite

Comment: @insta - May I ask where you found such cheap Lipo batteries? All the 22.2V Lipo battery packs I found are at least €70.

Comment: @kramer65: https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-1300mah-6s-35c-lipo-pack-450-helicopter-hk-trex-rave-e4-etc.html as a random example.  35C @ 1300mah will do 40A continuously for a half-minute or so.

Comment: What kind of motor, and how are you controlling it? It may work fine at 12V, if you don't need full rated speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 24 V at 8 amps, you'll need to supply 12 volts at 16 amps minimum. Add some inefficiency in the converter, and 20 amps is a good starting point. If, as you say, the motor will run half the time (and that may not be the case, depending on your control algorithm), average battery current will be 10 amps. A regular car battery will run about 45 amp-hr, so in theory you should be good for 4 or 5 hours. Of course, if you do this you won't be able to start your car, so you won't be able to recharge your battery.

So, if you really have 50% duty cycle, and the weather is warm, you might go 2 hours. 3 at the most. Anything more is really taking a risk. And if the motor is actually running full time (which it may), trying for more than about an hour is pushing your luck.

Of course, this assumes a new car battery. If your battery is getting old, you should expect an even shorter run time before you get in trouble.